# SQL: Compare tables returns Null but want a case statement

Tags: mysql, sql

The following SQL works fine but wondering if there is a way to create a case statement that prints a statement if the table is null.

```
SELECT A,B,C
FROM Table A
EXCEPT
SELECT A,B,C
FROM Table B
```

I have tried

```
SELECT A,B,C
FROM Table A
    CASE
    WHEN A IS null
    THEN 'Tables Match'
    ELSE 'Tables do not match'
    end as 'Check Table'
EXCEPT
SELECT A,B,C
FROM Table B

CASE
WHEN A IS null
THEN 'Tables Match'
ELSE 'Tables do not match'
end as 'Check Table'
```

but it still returned null

any help is appreciated.

Comment: Comparison to null is `IS NULL`, not `= NULL`. Otherwise it should work, although you didn't provide your entire procedure.

Comment: As stated this returns null. Makes no difference if  = or  IS.  What I would like is a statement instead of null... if possible

Comment: I think it will be easier for you to do so in the application layer, and not in the database layer.

Comment: @cdaiga I was thinking that aswell.